# PHP Android HTTP SEC_ERROR_EXPIRED_CERTIFICATE

Tags: php, android, httpclient

I am using following web service:

```
https://whizapi.com/api/v2/util/ui/in/indian-city-by-postal-code?project-app-key=myappkey&pin=110016.
```

I am accessing this service in my android app using **HttpClient** and in PHP using **file_get_contents**. It was working fine when suddenly my requests on both platforms started to fail.

After some digging I found that problem is due to **SEC_ERROR_EXPIRED_CERTIFICATE**.

Now may be I have to wait till the guys at **whizapi**, whom api services i am using, installed the security certificate.

Is it any way I can bypass this error, on both my android app and php server.

**EDIT**

Following is the warning/error **Mozilla Firefox** is showing:

> whizapi.com uses an invalid security certificate.
>
> The certificate expired on Thursday, February 23, 2017 21:24 PM. The current time is Thursday, February 23, 2017 22:45 PM.
>
> Error code: SEC_ERROR_EXPIRED_CERTIFICATE

Any way I can by pass this error in Android app and PHP scripting?